# Dojo mobile EdgeToEdgeList : firts list item hidden behind header

Tags: html, mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to dojo / dojo mobile.
I am building a screen with a header and a list of items beneath. Very
classical in mobile apps.

```
<body id="content" style="display: none">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="mainView"
    data-dojo-props="selected:true,scrollDir:'v'">

    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Main',fixed:'top'"></h1>

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
             data-dojo-props="label:'Take Picture...',
                              icon:'images/plus-30.png',
                              url:'TakePicture.html',
                              transition:'slide'">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
<script src="js/PhoneGapDemo.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script>
```

Problem : the first item on the list is hidden behind the header and not
visible.
(Same rendering in IBM Rich Page Editor, IBM Mobile App Simulator, Apple iOS
Simulator and iPhone iOS6)

I juste started the project, I don't have fancy CSS or other ... just
started from scratch, added the ScrollableView, the Header, the
EdgeToEdgeList and then the ListItems.

Workaround is to apply a style on the EdgeToEdgeList to move it 40px down. 
But it is not clean and breaks cross-platform compatibility (what if the
header is not always 40px height ?)

I am using DoJo 1.8

Thanks

Seb

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution other than the workaround you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is twofold

1. use style="visibility:hidden" in  element, as following

   `<body id="content" style="visibility:hidden">`
2. load "mobileDeviceTheme" explicitly with a  element instead of letting Dojo load it asynchronously  (this module needs to be loaded early to allow for proper height calculation)

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>`

before (the load of dojo/dojo.js)

Seb

Answer (score 0):

Hi even im new to this worklight, well im not sure but got to the properties (go to the design and right click on the edge-to-edge list and select properties) you can see the tag, style , Layout, All options.
go to styles and click the properties and change the postion / lay out. it might help.
please let me know if you get that right.